# Sum of two dedekind cut is a cut

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb R$, define the following:
$$
A_1+A_2= \{x + y: x \in A_1, y \in A_2\}
$$

I was able to prove that it is not equal to $\mathbb Q$ and isn't the empty set and but I can't prove the property that if $p_1 < x + y$ then it must be in $A_1+A_2$.

Comment: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wlzhang/dedekind-cuts.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take some $x\in A_1, y\in A_2, p_1 < x+y$.  You can use the fact that $A_2$ is a Dedekind cut to reason that $p_1-x < y$  implies that $p_1 - x \in A_2$, and therefore $p_1 = x + (p_1-x) \in A_1 + A_2$.